# How to get the row with the rowspan tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a pandas dataframe from a html table using BeautifulSoup and I get all the rows correctly except those that have the rowspan tag inside, i.e.  1 
This row is excluded from my dataframe. I tried to replace the rowspan tag with something else, i.e. class but the result is still the same. I am using html5lib parser because xml, and lxml dont work.
Can someone help me to get all the rows, including those with rowspan tag?

Comment: pls add you code and examples about your html ...etc

Answer (score 0):

Give you an example of using simplified_doc

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html = '''<table><tr rowspan="1"><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
<tr><td>21</td><td>22</td></tr></table>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
rows = doc.getElementByTag('table').trs
print ('-'*10,'all')
print (rows)
print ('-'*10,'contains rowspan')
print (rows.contains('','rowspan'))
print ('-'*10,'not contains rowspan')
print (rows.notContains('','rowspan'))
print ('-'*10,'td')
for row in rows:
  tds = [td.text for td in row.tds]
  print(tds)
```

result:

```
---------- all
[{'rowspan': '1', 'tag': 'tr', 'html': '<td>11</td><td>12</td>'}, {'tag': 'tr', 'html': '<td>21</td><td>22</td>'}]
---------- contains rowspan
[{'rowspan': '1', 'tag': 'tr', 'html': '<td>11</td><td>12</td>'}]
---------- not contains rowspan
[{'tag': 'tr', 'html': '<td>21</td><td>22</td>'}]
---------- td
['11', '12']
['21', '22']
```